# How to resolve this error "NoRegisteredProviderFound" when deploying to an azure webapp on Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, azure

The full error is:
NoRegisteredProviderFound: No registered resource provider found for location 'North Europe' and API version '2.0' for type 'servers'. The supported api-versions are '2014-01-01, 2014-04-01, 2014-04-01-preview'. The supported locations are 'northeurope, eastus, westus, southcentralus, eastus2, centralus, northcentralus, eastasia, southeastasia, japanwest, japaneast, westeurope, brazilsouth, australiaeast, australiasoutheast, centralindia, westindia, southindia, canadacentral, canadaeast'

This only happens when deploying the webapp with a database server, this happens regardless of whether I'm creating a new database server or connecting to one. The error still occurs with a v12 server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clive - this is bug in VS2015, if you can install the latest update it should fix the problem: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs2015-update2-vs.aspx

LMK if it does not resolve the problem for you.

Comment: can you comment on my SO question?


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37800291/azure-noregisteredproviderfound-when-creating-database-with-web-app