# Azure NoRegisteredProviderFound when creating database with web app

Tags: visual-studio, azure

As per [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37676310/how-to-resolve-this-error-noregisteredproviderfound-when-deploying-to-an-azure), I updated VS to update 2 but I still get the same error.

Creating a MVC + webapi project with Azure option selected. Select North Europe and populated with Azure details. 
Selected to create database.

Azure creates all resources part from the database. error shown:

```
Creating Microsoft Azure Web App
Creation of Microsoft Azure Web App failed. Following errors occured during the deployment:
Error during deployment for resource 'xxxWebApiDb' in resource group 'xxxWebApiGroup': NoRegisteredProviderFound: No registered resource provider found for location 'North Europe' and API version '2.0' for type 'servers'. The supported api-versions are '2014-01-01, 2014-04-01, 2014-04-01-preview'. The supported locations are 'northeurope, eastus, westus, southcentralus, eastus2, centralus, northcentralus, eastasia, southeastasia, japanwest, japaneast, westeurope, brazilsouth, australiaeast, australiasoutheast, centralindia, westindia, southindia, canadacentral, canadaeast'..
```

No errors if I choose not to create a database. I can create SQL DB's separately via Azure portal.

Comment: please check if the name of the db is unique for that given server or if a new server is getting created then its name must be unique .

Comment: I've just tried again. Gave it a name I consider would be unique and no change.

Comment: Can you check the version of the AzureSDK you have installed, and if it's <2.9, install the latest SDK and try again...

Answer (score 13):

As [bmoore-msft](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4962130/bmoore-msft) pointed out in the comments, updating the Azure SDK fixes this issue.

- Go to **"Tools"** menu
- Go to **"extensions and updates"**
- Find the **Azure SDK** and update it

Or go to the following link [here](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/features/azure-tools-vs.aspx), download & install.

---

While trying to update today (08/01/2017) I got a Runtime Error.
Simply refresh the page a few times until you get a download pop-up for the installation exe.

Comment: i tried it but it didnot work. then i downloaded the "Publish Profile" from azure console after creating a new service and while publishing from visual studio i imported this "publish profile". it worked. thanks