# Subscription is not registered for the resource type 'component' in the location 'Central US' during azure deployment from VS15

Tags: azure, deployment

I am trying to deploy the web app to Azure but facing error 
Error during deployment for resource 'xxxWebApiDb' in resource group 'xxxWebApiGroup': NoRegisteredProviderFound: No registered resource provider found for location 'North Europe' and API version '2.0' for type 'servers'. The supported api-versions are '2014-01-01, 2014-04-01, 2014-04-01-preview'. The supported locations are 'northeurope, eastus, westus, southcentralus, eastus2, centralus, northcentralus, eastasia, southeastasia, japanwest, japaneast, westeurope, brazilsouth, australiaeast, australiasoutheast, centralindia, westindia, southindia, canadacentral, canadaeast'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you check **the version of the AzureSDK** you have installed, and if it's < 2.9, install the latest SDK and try again.
Here a similar case, refer to the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37800291/azure-noregisteredproviderfound-when-creating-database-with-web-app).

Answer (score 7):

I just got an alternative.

1. Goto portal.azure.com
2. Create a web app/app service in Azure Portal.
3. Download publish profile.
4. Now come to visual studio, right click on web app you want to publish, click publish>Log In to your subscription > Click on Import > Select Downloaded Publish profile.
5. Done!

Enjoy.

Comment: A year on! I downloaded the latest Azure SDK and ran into the above issue. It was driving me bonkers! +1 from me. Saved me potentially hours of frustration.

Comment: What do you mean 'right click on the web app you want to publish'? Where? It's not in my local machine yet or in VS...

Comment: Right click inside Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

You have to register relevant resource providers with your subscription first (sql database in your example - namespace `Microsoft.Sql`). 
Azure CLI command to do this:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/azure-cli-arm-commands#azure-provider-commands-to-manage-resource-provider-registrations

See this too: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-common-deployment-errors#noregisteredproviderfound