# Create a web app in Azure for Xamarin Android

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure, asp.net-web-api, xamarin

[image: image of Visual Studio error during deployment]

I am getting this error in Visual Studio, during deployment.

Comment: rather than posting an image of the error, please take the time to copy and paste the actual text of the error message.

Comment: googling "missingregistrationforlocation" returns multiple hits.  Have you tried any of the suggested solutions?

Comment: ok if that helps

Comment: yes jason i have tried i am updating microsoft azure sdk may be it helps.i hope

Comment: If it is useful, please help to mark it as an answer that will help more communities easily to search.

Answer (score 1):

If your SDK version <2.9, please have a try use [Lastest Azure SDK](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/downloads/archive-net-downloads/) version. And there is a smilar [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41440345/subscription-is-not-registered-for-the-resource-type-component-in-the-location).